# onKeyDown on nested HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

I have a li element which consists of a button inside one of its div. onKeydown event triggers the parent li element and not the button. I believe the reason is li also has a onKeyDown attribute. Below is a code snippet of the same. How do I manage/separate out the two onKeyDown events?

```
<li
   id ='test'
   onKeyDown={handleLiClick}
>
  <div>Some Random stuff</div>
  <div> 
     <button
       onClick={handleButtonClick}>
      >
      <SomeComponent>
      </button>
  </div>
</li>
```

Please note handleButtonClick function listens to both Mouse and keyboard event.

Comment: Please share how the `handleButtonClick`  function listens to both click and keyboard. By my reading (https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#handling-mouse-events) , the `onClick` attribute only wires up listening to mouse click. Functions , generally, don't listen to events, they respond to them in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Your question has some unclear parts, but based on what I understand, I'll answer it. I think if you pay attention to these two things, you can achieve what you're asking: "How do I manage/separate out the two onKeyDown events?"

1-By default,an li tag doesn't respond to keyboard events. According to this document Keyboard events are only generated by input, textarea, summary and anything with the contentEditable or tabindex attribute. If not caught, they bubble up the DOM tree until they reach Document.[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event)
However, if you want the li element to be focusable and respond to keyboard events like keydown, you can add the tabindex attribute.

2-After that, to separate the two keyDown events, you need to pass different keys to the functions that execute when the keyDown event is triggered.

```
function handleKeyDown(event) {
  if (event.key === ' ') {
    console.log('space key down');
  }
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    console.log('enter key down');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like `event.stopPropagation()` in your `handleLiClick` method?

Comment: This is a good idea. Can you make your answer a code snippet of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this， If it helps, please give me a good
The stopPropagation() method prevents the event from further bubbling, ensuring that the event is only processed on the current target and not propagated to higher-level elements.

```js
function handleLiClick(event) {
  event.stopPropagation(); 
}
```